# What is reason of this error? Is that because connection closed from server-side or client-side?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I'm using Spring webclient to connect to the server.

I'm receiving this error sometimes, is that because connection is closed from server-side or the problem is in client-side?

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException:
    Connection prematurely closed DURING response

Suppressed:
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
            |_ checkpoint ? Body from GET https://*** [DefaultClientResponse]
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/796 . If this does not help out, please post your client code and also the API contract of the server